# Why TypeScript doesn't infer type from function signature?

Tags: angular, typescript

I've an issue in my Angular service with TypeScript type inferance. I'm new to TypeScript and I wonder why this code:

```
initializeTransaction(user: User, amount: number) {
  let params = {
    userId: user.id,
    amount: amount
  };
  return this.http.post<any>('/api/v1/payment/transaction/initialize', params);
}
```

where:

```
export class User {
  id: number;
}
```

gives me this payload:

```
{"userId":1,"amount":"2000"}
```

Shouldn't `amount` be a number?

**Edit:**
Here is the context of PaymentComponent:

```
export class PaymentComponent implements OnInit {

  private user = new User();

  submitted = false;
  redirecting = false;
  paymentForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private paymentService: PaymentService,
    private userService: UserService
  ) {
    this.userService.me().subscribe(response => this.user = response);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.paymentForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      amount: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$")]]
    });
  }

  get f() { return this.paymentForm.controls; }

  onPay() {
    this.submitted = true;

    if (this.paymentForm.invalid) {
      return false;
    }

    this.redirecting = true;
    this.paymentService.initializePage(this.user, this.f.amount.value)
      .subscribe(response => window.location.href = response.redirectUrl);
  }

}
```

Comment: types don't change runtime behavior, if `amount` got to be a string somehow it will still be a string when you assign it to `User`

Comment: When your code runs in the browser typescript does not exists anymore, it only does at development time. When your code is built (transpiled) into javascript there is no types anymore.

Comment: I've added the context in my question. Should I write `+this.f.amount.value` instead of `this.f.amount.value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the payload is interpreted in pure Javascript at runtime... so whatever the backend response has would be set in the variable.

the angular services and TypeScript itself do not remove the additional attributes from the json payload.

you can either change your backend to not serve the additional attributes you wouldn't want to have or customize your service to remove the attributes.

Comment: payload is usually about responses, are you talking about the value of the variable `params`?

Comment: I'm talking about the "Request payload" in my Firefox debugger tool.

Comment: your form value is a string, you could convert to number with `amount: parseInt(amount)` in your service